# Question on definition of differentiability

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, soft-question

We define differentiability on an open interval with (positive) lenght and it looks like this. $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is open and $f$ differentiable. My short question is could this interval be also $(-\infty,\infty)$ as well or does it necessarily be $(a,b)$ I know there are functions which are differentiable on every point of $\mathbb{R}$, but was not sure, and would to ask, since i do not know whether it is useful to speak of positive length when my interval is infinite long, Thanks.

another example would be the mean value theorem, here we also use always an interval which is finit (a,b)

Comment: Finite intervals are used because differentiability is, a priori, a local property. If you happen to have it everywhere you might as well use the whole real line.

Comment: For the Mean Value Theorem as I know it, you actually need a finite *closed* interval $[a,b]$ (because the "mean value" is $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, you need those endpoints), even though for it to be true, differentiability needs to hold only in its interior. If you try to extend that to the whole number line, the obvious problem is that that has no endpoints, so there is no mean value to compute. (Of course if you have a function that is differentiable on all of $\mathbb R$, you can restrict it to any finite interval $[a,b]$ and the MVT a fortiori holds for that.)

Comment: exactly after a while it made sense to me as well, you have the problem that its not well-defined anymore you could have inf-inf which you would have difficulties, it doesnt make sense at all to define it on the whole real line @TorstenSchoeneberg